# SQL Query and Return Two Row into One

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

- `POST`: information about the position

```
POST_ID | REPORTS_TO
--------+-----------
1       | 4
2       | 1
3       | 1
4       | NULL
```

- `EMPLOYEE`: record of which person is in which post

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | POST_ID | PERSON_ID
------------+---------+----------
1           | 1       | 1
2           | 2       | 2
3           | 3       | 3
4           | 4       | 4
```

- `PERSON`: information about the person

```
PERSON_ID | NAME
----------+-----
1         | BOB
2         | JIM
3         | FRANK
7         | PHIL
```

I want to return the results as:

```
WorkerName | SupervisorName
-----------+---------------
BOB        | PHIL
JIM        | BOB
FRANK      | BOB
PHIL       | (NULL)
```

I've tried this, but it just returns 7 rows. I need to combine the results below grouped by `postID`, but then I lose half the values:

```
SELECT First_Name
FROM post
JOIN employee
  ON employee.PostID = post.Supervisor_PostID
    OR employee.PostID = post.PostID
JOIN person
  ON person.PersonID = employee.PersonID
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how we can achieve this result fro that data. Also, what's the difference (in this context) between a person and an employee.

Comment: Person is for personal data, and employee is for their employment data. The reason for the split, is because they could also be on the customer table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `person` table twice with `post`s: once for the worker (which you access through bridge table `employee`), the other for the supervisor:

```
select pe1.name WorkerName, pe2.name SupervisorName
from post po
inner join employee em on em.post_id = po.post_id
inner join person pe1 on pe1.person_id = em.person_id
inner join person pe2 on pe2.person_id = po.reports_to
```